# XML processing error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am currently trying to create a restaurant menu by using a menu xml file. Everything has worked perfectly so far, I even created a helper function to simply setup all the tables I need, however when passing the "DRINKS" I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined". I'm extremely confused because this should technically (at least in my mind) work the same way as the rest of the data i processed. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in processing the "DRINKS" portion of the xml file?

Here is my javascript:

```
function processXML(data){
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xml = parser.parseFromString(data.responseText, "text/xml");

    //Process breakfast
    var html = document.getElementById("breakfast");
    var tempHtml = tableCreator(xml, "BREAKFAST");
    html.innerHTML += tempHtml;

    //Process brunch
    html = document.getElementById("brunch");
    tempHtml = tableCreator(xml, "BRUNCH");
    html.innerHTML += tempHtml;

    //Process lunch
    html = document.getElementById("lunch");
    tempHtml = tableCreator(xml, "LUNCH");
    html.innerHTML += tempHtml;

    //Process dinner
    html = document.getElementById("dinner");
    tempHtml = tableCreator(xml, "DINNER");
    html.innerHTML += tempHtml;

    //Process drinks

    html = document.getElementById("drinks");
    tempHtml = tableCreator(xml, "DRINKS");
    html.innerHTML += tempHtml;

}

//Simple table creator function to setup our menu
function tableCreator(xml, tag){

    var mainElement = xml.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes;
    var tempHtml = "<table>";
    for(var i = 0; i < mainElement.length; i++){
        var temp = mainElement[i].childNodes;
        tempHtml += "<tr>";
        for(var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){
            tempHtml += "<td>" + temp[j].innerHTML + "</td>";
        }
        tempHtml += "</tr>";
    }
    tempHtml += "</table>";
    return tempHtml;
}
```

Here is the xml file "restaurant_menu.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MENU>
  <BREAKFAST>
    <APPETIZER><NAME>Fruit Bowl</NAME><PRICE>10.90</PRICE></APPETIZER>
    <SALAD><NAME>Caeser SALAD</NAME><PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SALAD>
    <SOUP><NAME>Chicken Noodle</NAME><PRICE>5.90</PRICE></SOUP>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Omelet</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Scrambled Eggs</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <DESSERT><NAME>Apple Pie</NAME><PRICE>7.90</PRICE></DESSERT>
  </BREAKFAST>
  <BRUNCH>
    <APPETIZER><NAME>Fruit Bowl</NAME><PRICE>10.90</PRICE></APPETIZER>
    <APPETIZER><NAME>EggPlant Frits</NAME><PRICE>10.90</PRICE></APPETIZER>
    <SALAD><NAME>House Salad</NAME><PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SALAD>
    <SOUP><NAME>Chicken Noodle</NAME><PRICE>5.90</PRICE></SOUP>
    <ANTREE><NAME>French Toast</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Omelet</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Scrambled Eggs</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Hamburg</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <DESSERT><NAME>Apple Pie</NAME><PRICE>7.90</PRICE></DESSERT>
  </BRUNCH>
  <LUNCH>
    <APPETIZER><NAME>Calamari</NAME><PRICE>10.90</PRICE></APPETIZER>
    <SALAD>Caeser Salad<PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SALAD>
    <SALAD><NAME>Arugula Salad</NAME><PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SALAD>
    <SOUP><NAME>Chicken Noodle</NAME><PRICE>5.90</PRICE></SOUP>
    <SOUP><NAME>Italian Wedding Soup</NAME><PRICE>5.90</PRICE></SOUP>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Steak</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Hamburg</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Angel Hair Pasta</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <DESSERT><NAME>Tiramisu</NAME><PRICE>7.90</PRICE></DESSERT>
  </LUNCH>
  <DINNER>
    <APPETIZER><NAME>Calamari</NAME><PRICE>10.90</PRICE></APPETIZER>
    <APPETIZER><NAME>EggPlant Frits</NAME><PRICE>10.90</PRICE></APPETIZER>
    <SALAD>House Salad<PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SALAD>
    <SALAD><NAME>Caeser Salad</NAME><PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SALAD>
    <SOUP>Chicken Noodle<PRICE>5.90</PRICE></SOUP>
    <SOUP><NAME>Italian Wedding Soup</NAME><PRICE>5.90</PRICE></SOUP>
    <SOUP><NAME>Roasted Patato</NAME><PRICE>5.90</PRICE></SOUP>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Steak</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Hamburg</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Angel Hair Pasta</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <ANTREE><NAME>Roasted Duck</NAME><PRICE>20.90</PRICE></ANTREE>
    <DESSERT><NAME>Apple Pie</NAME><PRICE>7.90</PRICE></DESSERT>
    <DESSERT><NAME>Tiramisu</NAME><PRICE>7.90</PRICE></DESSERT>
    <DESSERT><NAME>Creme Brule</NAME><PRICE>7.90</PRICE></DESSERT>
  </DNNER>
  <DRINKS>
    <BEER><NAME>Bud Weiser</NAME><PRICE>5.90</PRICE></BEER>
    <BEER><NAME>Hefe Weissbier</NAME><PRICE>6.90</PRICE></BEER>
    <WINE><NAME>Cabernet Sauvignon</NAME><FROM>Napa Valley</FROM><PRICE>15.90</PRICE></WINE>
    <WINE><NAME>Margaux</NAME><PRICE>50.90</PRICE></WINE>
    <WINE><NAME>Pinot Noir</NAME><FROM>Napa Valley</FROM><PRICE>12.90</PRICE></WINE>
    <WINE><NAME>Chianti</NAME><PRICE>10.90</PRICE></WINE>
    <COFFEE><NAME>Star Bucks</NAME><PRICE>3.90</PRICE></COFFEE>
    <SODA>Coca Cola<PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SODA>
    <SODA>Sprite<PRICE>3.90</PRICE></SODA>
  </DRINKS>
</MENU>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasted this websites time. My fault. My teachers included XML file did not have a correctly closed  tag